# Responsive meta taking some fixed width even its not declared anywhere, it's showing after refresh. One time load working fine

Tags: css, angular, media-queries, responsive, meta-tags

I am using this meta to make the page responsive

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

My application is using Angular and the meta is working fine once, but when I reload or open with mobile, it took some fixed with on which 830. It looks like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=830;">
```

I am not sure how is coming fixed width and how to solve it. It must be

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

all the time so my application works well for responsive view.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I found something on core js file which is included from a 3rd party, just commented on this code and it's working fine now.

```
function orientationChange(){
var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=1024;');
} else {
   // viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=830;');
}
```

}